# Strange new bug\feature in Salesforce: new undocumented IP addresses are used each time callout is made: how to cope with this?

Tags: callout, address

I have implemented some logic to reconnect sandboxes through s2s connection after sandbox refresh and use self callouts for that, but apparently something has been changed in Salesforce recently which breaks my functionality.

Looks like now each time when I do callout from Salesforce, it changes IP address each time when callout is made. I believe before it was working fine.
I mean there was one IP address for several transaction and several callouts which made me possible to write some "Browser" class. I was able to identify salesforce IP Address in the list of Login History of my user and it was exposed, and I was able to add it to the Network Access whitelist.
Now it just says "Salesforce.com IP" but doesn't expose that IP.
When I try external tools to detect Salesforce IP it appears to be different at each HTTPCallout (not only each transaction) and these IP addresses

90.66.44.51,
 47.88.200.216,
 88.136.180.127,
 166.37.94.227,
 102.27.105.71,
 194.38.160.218,
 28.223.203.168,
 104.100.211.38,
 130.97.39.91,
 185.44.248.223,
 253.132.217.3,
 86.55.62.241,
 35.22.219.18,
 90.66.44.51,
 168.89.106.144,
 238.169.209.111 etc

are out of range of Salesforce IP Addresses documented  here:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003652

> IPv4 Networks IPv4 IP Address Ranges Date Added    ARIN
>
> 96.43.144.0/20
>   96.43.144.0 - 96.43.159.254
>
> 136.146.0.0/15
>   136.146.0.0 - 136.147.255.254
>
> 204.14.232.0/21
>   204.14.232.0 - 204.14.239.254
>          RIPE
>
> 85.222.128.0/19
>   85.222.128.0 - 85.222.159.254 April 14, 2015
>   185.79.140.0/22
>   185.79.140.0 - 185.79.143.254
>          APNIC
>
> 182.50.76.0/22
>   182.50.76.0 - 182.50.79.254
>
> 202.129.242.0/23
>   202.129.242.0 - 202.129.243.254

Does anyone knows what kind of new feature this is and if is it possible to turn this off or to get the complete list of Salesforce IP addresses to make it able to add to Network Access range?

I tried to add 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 but it says IP range too large

=====================================

Update: let me explain what is the problem.
So, when I try to make HTTPCallout from Salesforce to itself to login, it says:

1/4/2016 12:51:05 PM EET    Salesforce.com IP   Application Failed: Computer activation required    Browser test.salesforce.com

and sends me activation code to the email, but even if I use that code and sends another HTTPCallout it would be invalid, since another callout will be made from another IP Address and previous code would be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just check some of these IPs with [IP lookup](http://ip-lookup.net/index.php) and none of these seems to be owned by SFDC.

I think you have 4 ways to deal with it:

- There is possibility that the captured IP from your tool may not be correct.
- Use named credential and connected apps. And use it for API calls. http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-to-salesforce-integration-using-named-credentials-in-just-5-lines-of-code/
- Pass security token with your password so it does not check network IP
- Contact SFDC support and check if they change anything and what is their advice on how to do it.

Comment: I have tried to use security token but it didn't work, it says 'Incorrect password'

Comment: How are you passing the token ?  if my password is "Pass123" and my Token is "abcdefg1234567890" then i need to pass "Pass123abcdefg1234567890". So you need concatenate the password and token without space.

Comment: yes, I have concatenated them and it said it is wrong password

Comment: Can you try same thing with tool like eclipse which accept password + token ? make sure your IP is not white listed. I am 100% sure that this works if you do it right.

Comment: Strange, this issue is reproduced only on one sandbox on cs7 instance. Not sure but when I try to do the same thing from another sandbox on cs50 everything works fine. Anyway, I think I have found a workaround: I can callout cs7 sandbox instance from sandbox on cs50 instance